# Cannot preseed grub-installer/bootdev

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, grub, pxe, preseed

I would like to install Ubuntu to smallest HDD in my computer system config via preseed. It works fine but when smaller HDD not /dev/sda(eg /dev/sdb) I have an error "Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed". How can I bind my grub-installer/bootdev with debconf-set partman-auto/disk?

```
    d-i partman/early_command \
     string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(echo /dev/`lsblk -rndbo SIZE,NAME,TRAN | grep sata | grep sd* | sort -V | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f2`)"

d-i grub-installer/bootdev (what am i need to type here?)
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-encrypted
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      root-encrypted ::                                       \
              512 512 512 ext4                                \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              100% 100% 100% linux-swap                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ swap }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              10240 51200 -1 ext4                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ root }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out

## d-i partman/early_command \

```
 string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(echo /dev/`lsblk -rndbo SIZE,NAME,TRAN | grep sata | grep sd* | sort -V | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f2`)"
```

and just use

d-i grub-installer/bootdev /dev/sdb